# Forcing method call from mouseListener in instance

Tags: java, mouselistener

I have a class which extends jpanel and implements MouseListener.
In another class, I need to call a method when MouseListener occurs in the said class (without the use of static) as well as get the value of "e". Code explains this better.

```
public class DrawStuff extends JPanel implements MouseListener
{
//draws stuff
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
    {
     //need this e
    }
}

public class otherClass extends JFrame
{
    DrawStuff draw = new DrawStuff();
    add(draw);
    int[][] arr_which_cannot_be_passed;
    public void methodToBeCalled()
    {
        //e can be used here
    }
    //other JFrame components added
}
```

Draw.getE() would not be good since methodToBeCalled() needs to be called when a mouse is clicked, not manually checked every time and I'd rather not poll for the value.

Comment: You should implement some model of the state of the application. In the click listener update the model, and use the values in the model when drawing. It's completely up to you how you implement the model.

Comment: hege_hegedus I'm using MVC structure and this goes in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So otherClass is interested whenever DrawStuff has to process a mouse clicked event.

Various ways this interest can be registered and acted upon.

One way is to extend the API of DrawStuff so that you can register a mouse listener. DrawStuff then propagates its MouseClicked event by invoking the callback onto the registered listener (if there is one).

otherClass registers it's own MouseListener implementation to DrawStuff with this new API method - the implementation calling the 'methodToBeCalled'.

With this mechanism you have DrawStuff still decoupled from otherClass and ensures that mouse click events are processed by both instances.

EDITED for the sake of clarity please see below:

> public class DrawStuff extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
>
> private MouseListener ml;
>
> public void registerMouseListener(MouseListener ml) { {   this.ml = ml;
>   }
>
> //draws stuff public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
>       {
>            if (ml != null)   {      ml.mouseClicked(e);      }
>       } }
>
> public class otherClass extends JFrame {
>       DrawStuff draw = new DrawStuff();
>
> ```
> public void intialise() {
>
>     draw.registerMouseListener(new MoueListener() {
>            ....
>            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
>                methodToBeCalled();                
>            }
>            ....
>     }); 
> }
>
> public void do()
> {     add(draw);    
> }
>
>
>
> int[][] arr_which_cannot_be_passed;
> public void methodToBeCalled()
> {
>     //e can be used here
> }
> //other JFrame components added }
> ```

Comment: By API do you mean class? 

Also, how would you handle propogation in this case? I used to throw custom events in C# and catch them according to their messages but after some research it seems there isn't a java equivalent to this and I have to make use of interfaces correct?I still have a lot to learn XD.

Comment: Interface (Application Programming Interface). Propagation is easy - you just invoke the callback. MouseListener instance is registered with DrawStuff - in its own MouseClicked method it then invokes the callback on the registered listener (i.e registeredMouseListener.mouseClicked(e) )

Answer (score 0):

Let `otherClass` (instead of `DrawStuff`) implement `MouseListener`.

This will send the events after each mouseclick to the desired instance.

I would suggest these changes:

- do not implement `MouseListener` in `DrawStuff` anymore
- define a constructor (or a setter) in `DrawStuff` that accepts an external `MouseListener`
- let `otherClass` implement `MouseListener`
- when constructing `DrawStuff` add `this` as the `MouseListener`-parameter
- implement `mouseClicked` in `otherClass`
- You can use [`e.getComponent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentEvent.html#getComponent%28%29) to get the reference of the relevant "DrawStuff" instance

Your code could look like this:

```
public class DrawStuff extends JPanel// do not implement MouseListener anymore
{
//...draws stuff...

    public DrawStuff(MouseListener listener) // add MouseListener as constructor parameter (will be an instance of "otherClass")
    {
        //...create your components...

        // use the instance of "otherClass" as MouseListener
        component.addMouseListener(listener);
    }
}

public class otherClass extends JFrame
    implements MouseListener// let this Frame implement MouseListener
{

    // give "DrawStuff" a reference to "this" (as implementation of MouseListener)
    DrawStuff draw = new DrawStuff(this);

    //...other stuff...

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
    {
         methodToBeCalled(e);
    }

    public void methodToBeCalled(MouseEvent e)
    {
        //e can be used here
        //you can use e.getComponent() to get the reference of the relevant "DrawStuff" instance
    }

    //...other JFrame components added...
}
```

Comment: I can't since there are other elements in otherclass. This means that I cant get an accurate measurement of how large the stuff drawn will be and since the drawstuff contains a grid it is essential I know location relative to drawstuff

Comment: I also have multiple instances of drawStuff on the same JFrame, further complicating the issue

Comment: Tried it and it worked, but I have been told that passing the method and keeping functions and what is viewed separate is much better practice. But I really appreciate the answer